# X64 Exception Type 0x06 - Invalid Opcode Exception

Tags: 64-bit, opcode

I have an HP DL360 Gen10. After a Windows update and the scheduled restart, I'm not able to boot nor enter into the BIOS and I get this error after the first POST:

"X64 Exception Type 0x06 - Invalid Opcode Execution

Symptom: An Invalid Opcode Exception has occurred indicating that the processor tried to execute an invalid, undefined opcode, or an instruction with invalid prefixes"

[a picture with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zasBQ.jpg)

Things that I already tried and didn't fix the issue:

1. Cleared NVRAM
2. Booted with one RAM stick at a time
3. Disconnected the Smart Array Controller
4. Restarted the iLO by pressing the UID button for 5-9 seconds

I really don't know what happened here.

Comment: Are you able to access iLO? Looks like your updates installed a bios update component that is causing issues while loading certain firmware.

Comment: @PeterZhabin Yes, I'm able to access iLO. I didn't update the bios at all. This happened after a Windows 2016 Server update.

Comment: Well, Windows provides firmware updates through the same channel as drivers. What does ILO IML say about your failed boot attempts?